# Recommending sudoedit instead of sudo $editor?

Tags: discussion, answer-format

I notice that in some people's answers say "to edit the file, do sudo gedit $file" some people say "sudo nano $file" and of course "sudo vim $file"

By default doing "sudoedit $file" will open the file in the user's preferred editor. I think this is handy because documentation can be consistent regardless of what editor the user prefers. Thoughts?

Comment: what about `sudo sensible-editor file`?

Comment: @lfaraone The first time `sensible-editor` is run, it lets the user select what editor to use. If the first run is with `sudo` then it will presumably store this configuration information in the non-`root` user's configuration (as the default behavior of `sudo` is to use `$HOME` from the running user's environment), likely rendering the particular configuration file inaccessible (or at least unchangeable) by the non-`root` user. Therefore, I doubt it would be a good idea to recommend this approach.

Answer (score 6):

I slightly disagree. This assumes the user is competent with a text-mode editor which they might not be. When supporting a mixed range of user competency (which we are) I find it's often better to cater to the lowest common denominator. In this case that means keeping them in a GUI environment as much as possible.

`gksu gedit` for Gnome/Ubuntu and `kdesudo kate` for KDE/Kubuntu (etc) seem like safer bets. Experienced users could easily sub in their editor of choice.

Of course for things that have to be done via the command line, `sudoedit` is great. IMO this includes tasks where there are multiple commands to be fired off and it's not practical to keep opening Run dialogues.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you think for new users explaining how to set gedit to be $EDITOR would be a better way to go though?

Comment: @JorgeCastro In November '11, I commented **wrongly** that *(a)* setting the `VISUAL` environment variable as `gedit` causes `sudoedit` run `gedit` as root, writing root-owned config files to the user's home directory (like `sudo gedit` does) and *(b)* using `EDITOR` instead of `VISUAL` would avoid this. **I was totally wrong.** `sudoedit` runs an editor as the caller, edits a temp file, and writes changes as root *after* the editor is closed. And `sudoedit` uses `VISUAL` *and* `EDITOR` (and `SUDO_EDITOR`), so if my first claim *were* true, the "fix" would fail. **My apologies to everyone!**

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a great idea - for a few reasons:

1. I had no idea `sudoedit` even exisited! So plus one on learning something
2. This provides the asker of the question - and eventually other answer seekers - a uniform way of performing actions. I myself know enough that I personally love `nano` for text editing. But just like `Vi`, `nano` is a beast of its own to learn to use. For someone who is new and knows only of GUI editors, that's a big step to make.

Answer (score 1):

**sudoedit** is an abstract reference, that is it will point by default to the editor selected by the distribution, or if the default is overridden to whatever editor selected see http://www.cs-repository.info/.  This override likely would be caught by a system admin, but not by an inexperienced user (who could have actually made the changes).  The danger here is the non-default editor could have shell escapes.  An additional caution is that an example presented pedagogically would be different if the default editor had be changed to **vi** or **emacs** both of which have been defaults for **sudoedit** in the past, or other editor.  **vi** is currently the default choice of http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.html

**nano** is a specific GNU editor with no shell escapes (and is the default **sudoedit** editor in later distributions of Ubuntu).  When executed with the "`-B`" ( or "`--backup`") option it offers safety and relative ease for superuser editing using the terminal.

**gksu gedit** is excellent for this purpose and favored by the command-line phobic or command-line adverse.  I after 45 years in this business used it until I discovered **nano**.

My idea⋯offer **gksu gedit $file** or **nano -B $file** with the other as an alternative and leave **sudoedit** alone.

Personally, I would never recommend **sudoedit** to a non-sysadmin.

That's my 12₵ worth (2₵ in '65 dollars)

**O.K., another 12₵ worth…**

First of all, when I was first introduced to **sudo** I didn't like it. After all, when I first started using [computers](http://hpmuseum.net/images/2115A-2-filled-44.jpg), the terminal was a [real teletype machine](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/ASR-33_1.jpg).

But I've learned to go with the flow, and there were some very good reasons to use **sudo**, a good synopsis is [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/intro.html).  Basically for the inexperienced user it helps prevent unintended consequences when superusing (or super *like* using).

But the protection of **sudo** can be breached by shell escapes (i.e. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch30_26.htm), notably **vi**, which allows a user run commands in a subshell, as an superuser.

A senario is an inexperienced user finds out that he can change **sudo** while mucking about on the Internet(*i.e.* [diddling with `/etc/sudoers`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch30_26.htm)) to, for example, use **sudo** without requiring a password .  He does this and then discovers all the other *cool* things he can do. The unintended consequence here is that the inexperienced user may not grasp all the implications of `sudo visudo`.  Abstraction *e.g.* **sudoedit** and `sudo visudo` contribute to unintended consequences.

- Of course trying to protect users from these things is like herding cats.

**nano** is a great choice for inexperienced users (and for me who likes to eschew the command-line when practical) in that it is most like GUI editors.  I'm confident that's why Ubuntu selected it as the default editor of **sudoedit**.

But my thinking is to avoid abstraction unless it has obvious benefits, hence **sudo nano -B** vice **sudoedit** and occasionally `gksu gedit $file` (or `gksu jEdit $file` if I'm amped up).

- The nub of the discussion is how far to go herding cats.

Comment: I don't get why it wouldn't be a recommendation. For normal people they would get nano, and everyone else would get whatever editor they defined.

Comment: Jorge - I've expanding my thinking in an edit

Comment: As far as I can tell from the sudoedit manual, the editor doesn't run with superuser privileges, so that shell escapes aren't the danger you suggest.